# Nomination data does not match profile data

Tags: bug, election

I just nominated myself for the moderator election and under my nomination it says

> review history
>
> meta questions: 27 / +105
>
> meta answers: 57 / +140
>
> helpful flags: 114

but my profile on the main site lists 115 helpful flags and I have 9 helpful flags on meta. Why don't the numbers match?

Comment: caching. it's always caching.

Comment: I _believe_ this is caching. Going to check on it again in about 24 hours.

Comment: My last helpful flag was raise over a month ago... so I am going with zero based indexing.

Comment: Thanks for nominating !

Comment: @TimPost any ideas?